# groupby a column to get a minimum value and corresponding value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with three columns, shown below.

What I would like to do is get the minimum date for each id & the score on that day.

```
id       date        score
124      2020-01-01  3.4
124      2020-01-02  3.11
124      2020-01-03  2.97
124      2020-01-04  3.64
477      2020-04-03  0.9
477      2020-04-04  0.7
477      2020-04-05  1.1
477      2020-04-08  0.5
```

The output I'm looking for,

```
id       date        score
124      2020-01-01  3.4
124      2020-04-03  0.9
```

I am able to get the minimum date by using the groupby but not the score to go with it. I tried the agg function but think I'm using it wrong

Comment: `df.loc[df.groupby('id')['date'].idxmin()]`

Comment: I'm getting a ValueError. The id in my dataframe isn't a index, does that make a difference?

Comment: Nope the id I used wasnt an index either. what is the error? is your date a date or string: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Comment: File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 655, in wrapper raise ValueError

Comment: can you post the traceback? If you try `df = pd.read_clipboard()` then `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`  then `df.loc[df.groupby('id')['date'].idxmin()]` with the data you posted, this works

Comment: ah apologies, the date column was of type object not datetime, making that change and indeed it works. Thanks for your help. If you post your answer below I can make it as correct

Comment: i guessed so. thats okay , this has been asked before hence I have closed it. But I am glad I could solve your problem :)